# Does Lua evaluate values of nested tables differently when calling its length?

Tags: lua

To preface, I'm using repl.it rather than having Lua on my desktop. This could be the issue, but I can't be sure since I don't have easy access to another Lua interpreter.

I'm having an issue with a larger program, but the same issue is seen in the following snippet:

```
stuff = {}
list = {"hello"}
table.insert(stuff,list)
table.remove(list)
print(unpack(stuff[1]))
```

When ran, I expect it to print the unpacked table found at `stuff[1]`, which should be `"hello"` because that's the value of `list` when I set it. Using the preferred method of insertion and deletion, seen below, yields the same results.

```
test = {}
help = {"hello"}
test[#test+1] = help
help[#help] = nil
print(unpack(test[1]))
```

However, if I don't call the length but use a magic number or a constant, it works just fine, as in the two examples below.

```
what = {}
the = {"hello"}
what[1] = the
the = nil
print(unpack(what[1]))

how = {}
questionmark = {"hello"}
one = 1
what[one] = questionmark
questionmark = nil
print(unpack(what[one]))
```

Finally, this isn't present when not using nested tables, as in this example:

```
notnested = {}
nottable = "hello"
notnested[#notnested+1] = nottable
nottable = nil
print(notnested[1])
```

What's going on here? Am I misunderstanding the timing of declarations, doing something wrong, or is repl.it/Lua at fault?

This is the repl.it of the five examples above: https://repl.it/@typhirz/LightsalmonDenseCodeview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicol Bolas below provided some insight which led to my solution in my larger program. Instead of `stuff[1] = list`, I used `stuff[1] = {unpack(list)}` which forced it to make a new table, separate from `list`, which allowed me to manipulate `list` later without changing anything inside of `stuff`. Since this is a shallow copy, it doesn't work in all cases (notably if there are further nestings), so instead look into deep copies for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> table.remove(list)
> help[#help] = nil
> ```

These are not the same as this:

> ```
> the = nil
> ```

The first two manipulate the *table* stored in the variable `list`/`help`. The second one simply nil's out the *variable* `the`. The table stored in `list`/`help` has also been stored in the table `stuff`/`test`.

Changes to a variable are different from changes to the table *stored* in the variable.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The value in the table's registry is changing in the first two examples, and all that is stored inside `stuff` is the pointer to the registry, so if I change the value in the registry, then I change the value of it in both places.

How do I force the first table to use a different registry then? I want to be able to manipulate the second table without affecting the first one in any way.

Comment: @typhirz: Tables do not have "registries"; they store things. `list` and `help` are not tables; they're *variables*, which can *store* tables. Tables exist independently of the variables (or other tables) that store them. There is no "second table" and "first one"; they're all *the same table", simply stored in different locations and accessed in different ways.

Comment: That's essentially what I was saying, just using the word registry in a assembly-like way as a metaphor, since that's my background. And there are two tables in my example, `stuff` and `list` are variables that point to two different tables, and the first table stores the link to the second table, unless you mean there's only one table total in Lua. Anyway, I found a solution for the relatively simple case I'm using it for, which I'll edit into the original post.

Comment: @typhirz: "*which I'll edit into the original post.*" Don't do that. Answers go in the answer section. If you have an answer to provide, post it as an answer.